# Can I say that domain doesn't exist if Socket.Connect fails?

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to check if some email domain exist.

When `Dns.GetHostEntry(domain)` throw an exception I know for sure that the domain doesn't exist.

1. Can I say that if `Dns.GetHostEntry(domain)` succeeded then the domain does exists or even if `Dns.GetHostEntry(domain)` succeeded that doesn't mean (yet) that domain exists?
2. Can I say the same when `s.Connect` fails to connect? I mean if connect throw an exception can I say that such domain doesn't exist?

If (1) is true, so in order to check if domain exists (1) will be enough, right?

```
public static bool Lookup(string domain)
{
    if (domain == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("domain");

    try {
       IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(domain);
       var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipHost.AddressList[0], _dnsPort);

       return Transfer(endPoint);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
          ++attempts;
    }
    return false;
}
public static bool Transfer(IPEndPoint endPoint)
{
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts <= _attempts)
    {                            
        try
        {
             var s = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
             s.Connect(endPoint);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ++attempts;
        }
        finally
        {
            s.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to connect with a socket you're saying a few things:

- There is a network path from my machine to the target machine
- The network path is clear of firewall and other restrictions
- The target machine is hosting a service on the target port
- The target machine is accepting my connections on that target service

All of these occur **after** the hostname has been resolved to an IP.

So the answer to your question is *no*. If `Socket.Connect` fails it could be that the domain doesn't exist, or any of the above reasons (and perhaps more).

Comment: Also keep in mind that resolving the Domain to a host record is not sufficient (perhaps even wrong).  You need to lookup the MX record.  > set type=mx
> gmail.com
Server:  <snip/>
Address:  <snip/>

Non-authoritative answer:
gmail.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 30, mail exchanger = alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
...

Answer (score 0):

after some research I found out that checking **mx records** against dns will tell me if domain can receive emails or not. If DNS server do return mx records for the domain it only means that domain can receive emails. If no mx records are returned, so domain can not receive emails == such domain doesn't exist